# Google Experiments - can you run across the entire site?

Tags: google, google-analytics, javascript, a-b-testing

Is it possible to run a Google Experiment A/B test across an entire website, rather than just a single page and a variation?

Answer (score 1):

This [StackOverflow post tells how to set up an experiment for multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842332/google-analytics-content-experiments-possible-to-setup-variations-for-multiple).   [wal5hy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605487/wal5hy) says:

The solution is to use relative url for the variation page.

E.g. you have a number of product pages:

```
www.mysite.com/products/eggs.html
www.mysite.com/products/cheese.html
www.mysite.com/products/bread.html
etc.
```

For each page you have a matching variation page:

```
www.mysite.com/products/eggs.html?var=bigpicture
www.mysite.com/products/cheese.html?var=bigpicture
www.mysite.com/products/bread.html?var=bigpicture
etc.
```

You want to use all the product pages in 1 experiment.

Go To google Analytics Content Experiments:
For the orginal page choose ONE of the many product pages (e.g. www.mysite.com/products/eggs.html) (This is just to get the experiment code and provide GA with an example page)

For the variation page choose relative url and put ?var=bigpicture

Then place the javascript required for the experiment on ALL the original product pages you want in the experiment

[image: Google Content experiments Dynamic URL product pages]

For more information see: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664470&topic=1745208&ctx=topic